# Cucumber and WebDriver, opening chrome when it is not necessary

Tags: java, selenium-chromedriver, cucumber-java

I'm starting with **cucumber**, following some tutorials and such.
I have two feature files, one with basic stuff you see on cucumber's *"get started"*, another one from WebDriver's *"get started"*.

The tests run successfully, but  cucumber opens the browser even for the feature/steps that don't ask for it.

```
project
|--src/test/java/packages
                   |--StepDefinitions.java
                   |--RunCucumberTest.java
                   |--GoogleSearchSteps.java
|--src/test/resources/packages
                        |--google_search.feature
                        |--is_it_friday_yet.feature
```

is_it_friday_yet.feature:

```
Feature: Is it Friday yet?
  Everybody wants to know when it's Friday

  Scenario Outline: Today is or is not Friday
    Given today is "<day>"
    When I ask whether it's Friday yet
    Then I should be told "<answer>"

  Examples:
    | day            | answer |
    | Monday         | Nope   |
    | Tuesday        | Nope   |
    | Wednesday      | Nope   |
    | Thursday       | Nope   |
    | Friday         | YES    |
    | Saturday       | Nope   |
    | Sunday         | Nope   |
    | 12345                  | Nope   |
    | Icecream       | Nope   |
```

google_search.feature:

```
Feature: Google Search Cheese
  Example of how to test web pages with cucumber

    Scenario: Finding some cheese
   Given I am on the Google search page
   When I search for "Cheese!"
   Then the page title should start with "cheese"
```

StepsDefinition.java

```
import io.cucumber.java.en.Given;
import io.cucumber.java.en.Then;
import io.cucumber.java.en.When;

import static org.junit.Assert.*;


class IsItFriday {
    static String isItFriday(String today) {
        return "Friday".equals(today) ? "YES" : "Nope";
    }
}

public class StepDefinitions {

    private String today;
    private String actualAnswer;

    @Given("today is {string}")
    public void today_is(String today) {
        this.today = today;
    }

    @When("I ask whether it's Friday yet")
    public void i_ask_whether_it_s_Friday_yet() {
        actualAnswer = IsItFriday.isItFriday(today);
    }

    @Then("I should be told {string}")
    public void i_should_be_told(String expectedAnswer) {
        assertEquals(expectedAnswer, actualAnswer);
    }
```

GoogleSearchSteps.java

```
import io.cucumber.java.After;
import io.cucumber.java.Before;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedCondition;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;
import io.cucumber.java.en.Given;
import io.cucumber.java.en.Then;
import io.cucumber.java.en.When;

public class GoogleSearchSteps {

    private WebDriver driver;

    @Before
    public void createDriver() {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","mypath\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe");
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
    }

    @Given("I am on the Google search page")
    public void i_am_on_the_Google_search_page() {
        driver.get("https:\\www.google.com");
    }

    @When("I search for {string}")
    public void i_search_for(String query) {
        WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.name("q"));
        // Enter something to search for
        element.sendKeys(query);
        // Now submit the form. WebDriver will find the form for us from the element
        element.submit();
    }

    @Then("the page title should start with {string}")
    public void the_page_title_should_start_with(String titleStartsWith) {
        // Google's search is rendered dynamically with JavaScript
        // Wait for the page to load timeout after ten seconds
        new WebDriverWait(driver, 10L).until(new ExpectedCondition<Boolean>() {
            public Boolean apply(WebDriver d) {
                return d.getTitle().toLowerCase().startsWith(titleStartsWith);
            }
        });
    }

    @After()
    public void closeBrowser() {
        driver.quit();
    }
```

The tests are running ok, they are basically copy and paste from the tutorials with a few modifications, and they run with success also, the problem is really a browser window being opened for every test.

So, how can I make `WebDriver` be used only for the `GoogleSearch` feature?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The `@Before` will run several times. You have various options here but the core is to make your WebDriver a singleton somehow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To use `WebDriver` only for the Google Search feature scenarios you should use a [conditional hook](https://cucumber.io/docs/cucumber/api/#conditional-hooks). You can associate your `Before` hook with a following tag expression:

```
@Before("@browser")
public void createDriver() {
...
}
```

and in the feature file:

```
@browser
Feature: Google Search Cheese
  Example of how to test web pages with cucumber
  ...
```

Comment: Thanks, worked like a charm, I'll have to study know the annotations to use alongside cucumber. And for those in the future with a similar case, don't forget to put the "@browser" on all related methods, like the close one, otherwise some exceptions will occur. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Your `@Before` annotated function will spawn a new WebDriver instance for each test.

You might skip it with something like

```
@Before
public void createDriver(Scenario scenario) {
    if(!scenario.getName().equals("GoogleSearch")){
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","mypath\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe");
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
    }  
}
```

Note: you need to pass `scenario` to `createDriver()` method.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, and a fast one. Both answers here works, but I marked the other one as the accepted because it looks less "workaround" and/or rely more on the framework than on my scenario. Thanks anyway.